# How do I get the mean value of each hour of a xarray dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, mean, python-xarray

I have a datatset with secondly values. The dataconsitency is not so good so sometimes there are also days missing.
I want to get the mean value of every hour in this dataset. The time should also contain the date.
So that I get something like this:

2015-01-01T00:00:00', '2015-01-01T01:00:00',
'2015-05-01T02:00:00'.......
and the mean variables to it.

I tried:

```
ds_mean = ds.groupby("time.hour").mean()
```

But there it gives me a mean value of all hours a this time containing the dataset.

Then I tried to create a dataset for each day. But the problem is that the time only contains the hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of groupby, use [`ds.resample`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html). Groupby groups on the unique hour values (1-24) which appear in the data, whereas resample explicitly changes the frequency of a DateTimeIndex dimension:

```py
ds_mean = ds.resample(time="H").mean()
```

See the user guide section on working with [time series data](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/time-series.html) for more info and examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. The complete notation would be:  ```ds_mean = ds.resample(time='H').mean() ```